# number of integers having at least one even digit

Tags: number-theory

if we have a range specified (say $[A,B]$) then how can we find efficiently the number of integers in this range which have at least one even digit $(0,2,4,6,8)$? One way would be to iterate through all integers in this range and for each check the digits. However for large difference in values of $A$ and $B$ this method may not be suitable (say $A = 1$ and B = $10^{10}$) .

E.g if $A = 1$ and $B = 25$ then the required answer is $15$: $(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,21,22,23,24,25)$

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find (1) The number of integers in the range, and (2) the number of integers in the range having only odd digits.  Then subtract.

Comment: Thanks Michael , but wouldn't this solution lead to finding efficiently the integers having only odd digits ?

Comment: Yes, but *only* odd is significantly simpler than *at least one* even.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to find numbers with only odd digits. Let's call them *good* for brevity.

Let $f(k)$ count *good* numbers under $10^k$. Namely $f(k) = 5^k + 5^{k-1}+\dots +5$. Note, $5^i$ counts *good* numbers that have exactly $i$ digits.

Let $g(N)$ count *good* numbers, lower than $N$. If $N = \overline{d_n\dots d_0}$ and $d_k$ is the most significant even digit then $$g(N) = f(n) + \bigg \lfloor \frac{d_n}{2} \bigg \rfloor 5^n + \bigg \lfloor \frac{d_{n-1}}{2} \bigg \rfloor 5^{n-1}+ \dots +\bigg \lfloor \frac{d_k}{2} \bigg \rfloor 5^k$$ This requires a bit of explanation. For example, consider $N = 5129$. The first term takes into account all numbers in interval $[0, 1000)$ the second term counts numbers in $[1000, 5000)$, third in $[5000, 5100)$, fourth in $[5100, 5120)$, the summation then stops because all numbers in the remaining interval have an even digit. Note that $\big \lfloor \frac{d_i}{2} \big \rfloor$ in the number of odd digits lower than $d_i$.

Finally, $h(A, B) = g(B+1) - g(A)$ counts *good* numbers in interval $[A, B]$. Therefore $B+1 - A - h(A, B)$ is the number you are looking for.

Comment: Your expression for $g(N)$ is not correct, for example $g(20)=g(29)$. To find the good numbers $\le N$. you should (apart from $f(n)$) rather count $\lfloor \frac {d_k+1}2\rfloor 5^k$, and that only if all $d_i$ with $i>k$ are odd!

Comment: You're right, i didn't consider that $d_i$ can be even. I'll fix that right away. I didn't understand your other comment though. Why $d_k +1$? Is it to replace $f(n)$? If no, then $g(10) = 10$, if yes then $g(20) = 5$. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

For boundaries given as powers of 10, the answer is straightforward.

There are 5 **single-digit** numbers having only odd digits.

To extend the number of digits, there are 5 odd digits that can be added to the left.

Thus, there are $5^n$ numbers between 1 and $10^n$ with only odd digits.

So, in this range, there are $(10^n-5^n)$ with at least one even digit

Comment: No, there are $5^n$ numbers that have exactly $n$ odd digits. I'm certain that leading zeroes don't count.